# Way to create a multi language inputfield

Tags: javascript, html, forms, multilingual

I have a form with an inputfield. When i write text into it containing umlauts, save the values to db and reload the page, i see the written text with the umlauts in the form as i typed them in. Example: I type `Bär`, after saving ang reloading the page i see `Bär`.

Now, the problem is when i insert russian or chinese letters they show up as expected.
But when i save them to db and reload the page i get the wrong representation of the characters.

Example: I write `Москва`. After saving the form and page reload i see `&#x41c;&#x43e;&#x441;&#x43a;&#x432;&#x430;`. This looks like html entities that do not get displayed correctly, but i think this are unicode hex character codes.

**How can i store and retrieve such foreign letters that they are displayed correctly in my html form?**

Answer (score 1):

First of all try by adding
`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">`
If that does not work, check default collaction in database and table. I'm always using utf8_general_ci when I have to work with translations and that work for me

Comment: meta tag is <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8559-1"> - this cannot be changed unfortunatly. But fiddling with the charset might indeed help +1

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution myself.

Actually the values of the inputfield get utf-8 encoded first and then cp1252 encoded before they get written to the database.

When i retrieve the inputfield data from the database i need to call this little replacement (perl code)

```
$inputfield_text=~ s/&(#[xX]?[0-9a-fA-F]+;)/&$1/g;
```

before i output the string.